# Crbug/1173575, non-JS module files deprecated & Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

To be quick and concise, my localhost:8080 was originally working but stopped loading up after a couple times running my js script.  I went through all the methods hear and eventually found that changing the launch.json file to use the file rather than chrome fixed the problem.  While this is a temporary fix is there another solution.  Yes I did check the network settings for the chrome dev console was set to no throttle instead of 'offline'.  Below is the code for the launch file i have tailored for the specific html file.

'''
"version": "0.2.0",
"configurations": [
{
"type": "chrome",
"request": "launch",
"name": "Launch Chrome against localhost",
"file": "//my personal path//project_file//index.html"
}
'''
While that works for now, when spinning up the local host, it works, but the js script is not running.  The only code in it is console.log('Hello World') as this is the beginning of my project.  The js script is in the same project_file as the index.html file shown above.  Could somebody please explain to me like I am 5 as to how to fix this.  This issue has singlehandedly given me more problems than all linear algebra did last semester.

Update:  After playing around with another kernel through anaconda, it seems like everytime I am actually forced into adding a configuration for running the .js script the localhost will no longer load.  Anybody know how to fix this?

Comment: The error in the title is printed by the built-in "URL not found" error page and it's about JS modules of the browser built-in UI and not yours. If you have git history of your project, try bisecting the regression.